# Jupyter can not render Latex mathematical equations, Typesetting math 0%

Tags: latex, jupyter-notebook

My jupyter notebook can not render Latex mathematical equations properly, even the most simple notation $x_i$ can not be rendered, on the left bottom of the page, there is an icon showing: Typesetting math 0%.

As for now, I think it's because my notebook contains to much content, more than 3000 lines of code and texts, is this the reason that the latex can not be rendered, is it possible to reload latex in my file?